# NSTimer iterating by 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a timer that I want to iterate once every second, but the counter is iterating by 4 each time and I'm not sure why. it prints: 4,4,8,8,12,12,16,16,20

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFunction:) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];

-(void)timerFunction:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"%d", timerCounter);
    timerCounter += 1;
    NSLog(@"%d", timerCounter);
    if(timerCounter >= 20){
        [self kestrelAlert];
        timerCounter = 0;
        [[self cancelButton] setHidden:YES];
    }


}
```

Comment: Those two `NSLog` can't generate the output you show in your question. If there is only one timer, nothing else changes `timerCount`, and your start `timerCount` at `0`, it would print `0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 ... 18 19 19 20` and then start over at 0 showing the same sequence again. If you incremented by 4 and started at 0 you would get `0, 4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16, 20`. Maybe you only want one `NSLog`.

Comment: The usual answer is: The timer is increased by 4 because you wrote code that did it. Find that code. Set a breakpoint everywhere timerCounter is mentioned. If your code does things you didn't expect, it's because you told it so. There are no gremlins hidden, it's your code doing it. It's your job finding out why.

Comment: it's only being incremented by 1, there is no other place in the code where it is incremented

Comment: So how many other timers are running that call that action?

Comment: it's only called once from a button in an alert view

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you call 2 times so before assign do

```
if (timer == nil) {
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFunction:) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
}
else {
    // active
}
```

Also you print it twice

```
NSLog(@"%d", timerCounter); // 1
timerCounter += 1;
NSLog(@"%d", timerCounter); // 2
```

Comment: Assuming the timer was started on the main queue, multiple timers wouldn't change the output.